# How to document/docstring a function whose argument/return type is dynamic?

Tags: python, docstring

Using the `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` functions as examples.

How to indicate/document/docstring the type of the argument in which `pickle.dump()` receives or the type of the value in which `pickle.load()` returns?

Here is an example of [Google Style Python Docsting](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html). As you can see, a normal function's argument type and return type are static and explicitly documented:

```
def function_with_types_in_docstring(param1, param2):
"""Example function with types documented in the docstring.

`PEP 484`_ type annotations are supported. If attribute, parameter, and
return types are annotated according to `PEP 484`_, they do not need to be
included in the docstring:

Args:
    param1 (int): The first parameter.
    param2 (str): The second parameter.

Returns:
    bool: The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

.. _PEP 484:
    https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

"""
```

But sometimes an argument/return type is dynamic. Not even [pickle.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pickle.py) provides and example of documenting its functions' argument/return object type.

Answer (score 0):

Only some of the examples show the return type statically defined in the docstring. The example below, from the link posted in the question, is an example where the return type is indicated in the function signature via type  hinting.

There are several ways to indicate multiple types (e.g. `Union[int, str, float]`) so pick which method works for your scenario.

```py
def function_with_pep484_type_annotations(param1: int, param2: str) -> bool:
    """Example function with PEP 484 type annotations.

    Args:
        param1: The first parameter.
        param2: The second parameter.

    Returns:
        The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

    """
```